# Encode var_dump with Base_64

Tags: php

I'm doing an experiment again, now, i'm tryng to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(atob("<?php var_dump(base64_encode(include("index.php")));?>"));
</script>
```

well, the problem is the output hasn't base64 encode. if i try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(atob("<?php base64_encode(var_dump(include("index.php")));?>"));
    </script>
```

It returns me the same thing, if i try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(atob("<?php echo base64_encode(var_dump(include("index.php")));?>"));
        </script>
```

Is the same too...

Can you help me, please? Thank you, a lot

Comment: Try 'index.php' instead of "index.php"... The problem may be caused by wrong quotes

Comment: I tried too.. and i'm trying again right now, but it's the same situtation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encoding the return value of `include`. Not the output of the included script. Use the output buffer using [ob_start()](http://php.net/ob_start) and friends to capture the output.

Mind: Doing this looks like a bad architecture ... thre should be a function returning the result of the included file as string, no ob hack.

Comment: Well, finally I tried with ob_start():

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(atob("<? ob_start();
include_once('index.php' );
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo base64_encode($out); ?>"));
</script>

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `var_export` instead of `var_dump` because `var_dump` just dumps out the variable and does not return anything.  See the documentation of the both:

`var_dump` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

`var_export` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php

Also your quotes are not right, try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(atob("<?php base64_encode(var_export(include('index.php'), true));?>"));
</script>
```